# Make elements semitransparent but the one being hovered

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to use the :not selector combined with :hover to make elements that is not being hovered semitransparent.

What I want to achieve:

1) Every element is 100% in opacity from start

2) When an element is being hovered it should stay at 100% opacity and the rest get 50% opacity.

I tried something like:

```
.news-item:not(:hover) {
    @include opacity(0.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the standard selector to make all of the items 50% opaque and override it with `:hover` to make the hovered item 100% opaque.

See the fiddle below for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/25784cvg/

**EDIT**:
Looking at the question again, that's not what you're asking. Apologies. Please see the updated fiddle below for an example that starts with all items at 100% opacity.

https://jsfiddle.net/25784cvg/1/